# Match and replace misspelled words in a string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, text-mining, text-processing

I have a list of phrases, in which I want to replace certain words with a similar word, in case it is misspelled.

```
library(stringr)
a4 <- "I would like a cheseburger and friees please"
badwords.corpus <- c("cheseburger", "friees")
goodwords.corpus <- c("cheeseburger", "fries")

vect.corpus <- goodwords.corpus
names(vect.corpus) <- badwords.corpus

str_replace_all(a4, vect.corpus)
# [1] "I would like a cheeseburger and fries please"
```

everything works perfectly, until it finds a similar string, and replaces it with another word

if I have a pattern like the following:

`"plea"`, the correct one is `"please"`, but when I execute it removes it and replaces it with `"pleased"`.

What I am looking for is that if a string is already correct, it is no longer modified, in case it finds a similar pattern.

Comment: Could you show the negative example, it is not clear to me?

Comment: `string<- c("tre", "tree", "teeasing", "tesing")

goodwords<-c("tree", "three", "teasing", "testing")

badwords<- c("tre", "thre", "teeasing", "tesing")

vect.corpus <- goodwords
names(vect.corpus) <- badwords


a <- str_replace_all(string, vect.corpus)
 "tree"   **"treee"**   "teasing" "testing" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_replace_all` takes regex as the pattern, so you can `paste0` word boundaries `\\b` around each `badwords` so that a replacement will only be made if the whole word is matched:

```
library(stringr)
string <- c("tre", "tree", "teeasing", "tesing") 
goodwords <- c("tree", "three", "teasing", "testing") 
badwords <- c("tre", "thre", "teeasing", "tesing") 

# Paste word boundaries around badwords
badwords <- paste0("\\b", badwords, "\\b")

vect.corpus <- goodwords 
names(vect.corpus) <- badwords 

str_replace_all(string, vect.corpus) 
[1] "tree"    "tree"    "teasing" "testing"
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to keep track of which strings are the longer strings.

This is what `badwords` looks like after pasting:

```
> badwords
[1] "\\btre\\b"      "\\bthre\\b"     "\\bteeasing\\b" "\\btesing\\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to perform progressive replace. e.g. you should have multiple set of `badwords` and `goodwords`. First replace with `badwords` having more letters so that matching pattern is not found and then got go for smaller ones.

From the list provided by you, I would create 2 sets as:

```
goodwords1<-c( "three", "teasing") 
badwords1<- c("thre", "teeasing") 

goodwords2<-c("tree", "testing") 
badwords2<- c("tre", "tesing")
```

First replace with 1st set and then with 2nd set. You can create many such sets.